# Rails - model relationship suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

Is it possible to define the following relationship:

1. A 'student' belongs to a 'group'
2. A 'group' has many 'courses' and many 'students'
3. A 'student' has many 'courses' through the 'group' it belongs to

I know how to do it with one more table(adding a student_course table which holds the id of the student and the course it belongs to and then saying that the a student has_many :courses, through: :student_course).

In other words, could it be implemented just by editing the following tables?

```
class Student
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group
  has_many :students
  has_many :courses
end

class Course
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: In order to say "one more table", you need to make clear what tables you have in mind, and you have not stated that.

Comment: Hey Sawa, I just added the tables I have already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it with a Rails class method, but you can just implement it manually.

```
class Student
  belongs_to :group

  def courses
    group.courses
  end
end

class Group
  has_many :students
  has_many :courses
end

class Course
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: I have to go over some basic stuff again, I guess... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try below associaion

student.rb

```
belongs_to :group
has_many :courses, through: :group
```

group.rb

```
has many :courses
has many :students
```

course.rb

```
belongs_to :group
has_many :students, through: :group
```

Comment: @KristiyanTsvetanov ohh it was mistake, updated my answer, thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @KristiyanTsvetanov did you try my solution ?